# Es6 way to convert object key value to one single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I want to convert all data into one object,

```
let d = {
  "Coupon_Code": "code",
  "Coupon_Name": "namie",
  "Coupon_Desc": 1000,
  "selectedCity": [
    {
      "Coupon_City_Name": "xyz"
    }
  ],
  "selectedCategory": [
    {
      "Coupon_Category_Name": "Shopping"
    }
  ],
  "selectedCompany": [
    {
      "Coupon_Company_Name": "Shopper Stop"
    }
  ],
  "selectedState": [
    {
      "Coupon_State_Name": "abc"
    }
  ],
  "Coupon_Date": "2222-02-22",
}
```

i tried some methods of Object like `keys` , `entries` but dont no what to use.
**Final output should be**

```
let d = {
  Coupon_Code: "code",
  Coupon_Name: "namie",
  Coupon_Desc: 1000,
  Coupon_City_Name: "xyz",
  Coupon_Category_Name: "Shopping",
  Coupon_Company_Name: "Shopper Stop",
  Coupon_State_Name: "abc",
  Coupon_Date: "2222-02-22",
};
```

what's the best and optimum way to have above result using Venila Js and Es6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the original object. If the entry's value is an array merge the 1st element, if not merge the original key and value. You can merge the properties into the object using [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals):

```js
const data = {"Coupon_Code":"code","Coupon_Name":"namie","Coupon_Desc":1000,"selectedCity":[{"Coupon_City_Name":"xyz"}],"selectedCategory":[{"Coupon_Category_Name":"Shopping"}],"selectedCompany":[{"Coupon_Company_Name":"Shopper Stop"}],"selectedState":[{"Coupon_State_Name":"abc"}],"Coupon_Date":"2222-02-22"};

const result = Object.entries(data)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => ({
    ...r,
    ...Array.isArray(v) ? v[0] : { [k]: v }
  }), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
let d = {"Coupon_Code":"code","Coupon_Name":"namie","Coupon_Desc":1000,"selectedCity":[{"Coupon_City_Name":"xyz"}],"selectedCategory":[{"Coupon_Category_Name":"Shopping"}],"selectedCompany":[{"Coupon_Company_Name":"Shopper Stop"}],"selectedState":[{"Coupon_State_Name":"abc"}],"Coupon_Date":"2222-02-22"};

d = Object.entries(d).reduce((a,[k,v]) => {
  // If the value is an array, iterate over it to merge into the resultant object
  if(Array.isArray(v)) Object.assign(a, ...v)
  else Object.assign(a, {[k]:v}) // if it is not an array, merge into resultant object
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a recursive approach.

```js
const
    fn = o => Object.assign(...Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => Array.isArray(v) ? Object.assign(...v.map(fn)) : { [k]: v })),
    d = { Coupon_Code: "code", Coupon_Name: "namie", Coupon_Desc: 1000, selectedCity: [{ Coupon_City_Name: "xyz" }], selectedCategory: [{ Coupon_Category_Name: "Shopping" }], selectedCompany: [{ Coupon_Company_Name: "Shopper Stop" }], selectedState: [{ Coupon_State_Name: "abc" }], Coupon_Date: "2222-02-22" },
    result = fn(d);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `... Object.assign(...v.map(fn)) ...` is calling itselft with `fn`.

Comment: Oh my bad. Didn't see that. Rather elegant.

Answer (score 1):

A possible iterative solution is:

```
function flatten(obj) {
    let r = {}
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            Object.assign(r, value[0]);
        } else {
            Object.assign(r, {[key]: value});
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
const d = { Coupon_Code: "code", Coupon_Name: "namie", Coupon_Desc: 1000, selectedCity: [{ Coupon_City_Name: "xyz" }], selectedCategory: [{ Coupon_Category_Name: "Shopping" }], selectedCompany: [{ Coupon_Company_Name: "Shopper Stop" }], selectedState: [{ Coupon_State_Name: "abc" }], Coupon_Date: "2222-02-22" };

function toSingleObj(obj) {
    var result = {};
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key,value]) => {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            Object.entries(value[0]).forEach(([k,v]) => {
                result[k] = v;
            });
        } else {
            result[key] = value;
        }
    });
    return result;    
}


console.log("Result: ", toSingleObj(d));
```